# Comparator.reverseOrder() vs Collections.reverseOrder()

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

Is there a difference between the two? If so, what is it?

When I used them for a priority queue, the both sort it the same way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use a good IDE, it's very easy to see the source code of the Java Runtime Library methods. E.g. in Eclipse you press F3 when cursor is on the method.

If you do that on the `Comparator.reverseOrder()` method, you'll see:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> reverseOrder() {
    return Collections.reverseOrder();
}
```

***Conclusion:* They are exactly the same.**

Comment: From an implementation and performance point of view, they are the same. But `Collections.reverseOrder()` is not type safe, as it doesn’t enforce the type argument to be a subtype of `Comparable`. So `Comparator.reverseOrder()` is preferable.